# Most inefficient algorithm to visit each elements of a 2d array once

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, panoramas, longest-path

I'm creating panorama images, and for this I use a camera that I move programmatically step by step. The images are captured rows by rows.

So basically the captures can be seen as some kind a 2d array:

```
[ 0, 1, 2, 3 ] # row 1
[ 4, 5, 6, 7 ] # row 2
```

Where the camera moves sequentially through the numbers.

I noticed that if a car moves in front of the camera and follows the same pace as the camera, the car appears on every picture and the panorama looks weird.

So, I had the following idea: move the camera in a non-sequential order that way the car is very likely to be only captured once. I then thought about how to capture the images in a way that the camera travels the most between each position.

I found a way for single-row panoramas. Basically it start at the beginning, jumps half way right, goes back half-way left minus 1, and repeats.

Here are examples:

```
# 1x5 --> [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]          # sequential indices: 0 3 1 4 2
# 1x6 --> [0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5]       # sequential indices: 0 3 1 4 2 5
# 1x7 --> [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]    # sequential indices: 0 4 1 5 2 6 3
# 1x8 --> [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7] # sequential indices: 0 4 1 5 2 6 3 7
```

To be clear, this means that for 1x6 (0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5) the camera moves as follow:

```
x----- # pos 1
---x-- # pos 2
-x---- # pos 3
----x- # pos 4
--x--- # pos 5
-----x # pos 6
```

So basically it jumps all the time by at least `n/2`, which looks optimal as no capture ends up being the neighbor of another one and the distance between captures looks maximized and fluctuates very little.

The simplified code I use is something like:

```rb
def index_for(n, cols)
  col = n % cols
  if n.even?
    col/2
  else
    (col / 2.0).ceil + (cols / 2.0).ceil - 1
  end
end

# Sequential indices [0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3]
seq = (0..6).map{ |i| index_for(i, 7) }

# Visualization [0, 2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
(0..6).map{ |i| seq.index(i) }
```

I tried making it work with several rows, and almost got there but then gave up. Here are examples of the idea I had:

```
 # 3x4
 [0,  2, 9, 11]
 [4,  6, 1,  3]
 [8, 10, 5,  7]

 # 2x5
 [0, 2, 5, 7, 9]
 [4, 6, 8, 1, 3]
```

If you look at the numbers, we see that the left side is usually simply the even numbers, and the right side are odd numbers but shifted in a modulus way. This shifting of the odd numbers is tricky to algorithmize, because the logic change slightly depending on the rows/cols being even/odd.

At the moment I ignore the rows and simply reapply the same algorithm for each rows. That means the 2x5 is done like this:

```
 [0, 2, 4, 1, 3]
 [5, 7, 9, 6, 8]
```

So, here are my questions:

- What is the best algorithm to achieve what I want, with multiple rows? I read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem and I think it'd be possible to construct a graph where there exist paths between all nodes of the grid, and the weight for each edge would be the distance between the nodes. This sounds very complicated and not easy to code tho.
- What would be the simplest/most practical algorithm to apply for multiple rows? I'm okay with "good-enough" solutions (the dimensions of the grid should remain within 1x3 to 3x9). I *don't* want solutions based on randomness, because I want the captures to always happen in the same order each time the panorama is captured.

**EDIT**: additional informations: the car usually moves slowly (at the speed of the sequential captures), so jumping around *is* a good way to avoid repetitions. It's also better to see the car in 2-3 tiles than in 7 of them if the car moves exactly at the speed of the camera (this happened). The panoramas are usually around 180°, but 360° should be supported. There's a pause of around 3 seconds between each image capture. The panoramas are mostly about capturing the construction of giant construction sites (buildings), but sometimes a car or a person walks in front of the building. We don't care about the moving parts, the goal is to capture the building and minimize the person/car photobombing the panorama.

Comment: You write *I then thought about how to capture the images in a way that the camera travels the most between each position.* For 7 steps, you move 0-2-6-1-3-5. The diffs are 2-4-5-2-2, so the maximum diff is 5, while the minimum diff is 2. Shouldn't it be possible to deal higher diffs for lower, to have a max diff(diff) of 1? 2-4-5-2-2 → 3-4-4-2-2 → 3-3-4-3-2 → 3-3-3-3-3? What about "0-3-6-2-5-1-4"? Diff: 3-3-4-3-4-3? A problem here, is, that for a 360° panorama, picture 0 and 6(=last) are adjactant, so diff 0-6 would be 1, not 6, and d(4) would be 1. ...

Comment: For the practical usage, I suspect that this will only work by incident. Faster cars will still be captured multiple times, or cars being more far away. Cars, travelling in the opposite direction? If a car isn't captured as a whole in one image, it will look weird as ½ car or ¼ car. :). But the algorithmic question is still interesting. Do we talk about 360°? Often panoramas are only very wide, but not a full turn around.

Comment: Another question I have is about 2 or more rows. Is it, to capture more of the view in the y axis, like before in the x axis? Wouldn't you try to get the top of the bus and the bottom together? Do you wan't to capture rockets taking off? Or is the picture thing just a made up example? What is the consideration for the connection of the row? Distance from each element in the first row to corresponding element in the second, while each element has to stick to its row?

Comment: @userunknown: I edited the question to answer your questions. About the diff question, you missread the moves. 0-2-4-1-3-5 means start at 0 (index 0), then go to 1 (index 3), then to 2 (index 1), then to 3 (index 4)...

Comment: That doesn't make sense, or does it? 0-2 start at 0, ok so far. Then go to 2, but 2 is neither the index, nor the value at index 2, since in the beginning, values and indexes are the same, which is a reasonable choice to explain something. Or what is the meaning of '2'. You could name the pics abcdef, to avoid the irritation of index and value. You mean 024135  stands for index 031425 or adbecf, but I don't see a mapping. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you look at the part in my post that says "To be clear, this means that for 1x6 (0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5) the camera moves as follow:" and tell me what is not clear? I added "sequential indices" to the examples as well, as my notation is more like "visual positions".

Comment: My question is, what these numbers mean: (0, 2, 4, 1, 3, 5). Where do they come from? It's not the index, since that is (0 3 1 4 2 5). It's not the stepwith with modulo, since that is (3,4,3,4,3).

Comment: They come from the index of the number returned by the `index_for` function that I put in the code example. Look at the `# Visualization` part of the code example. Basically these numbers represent how you should jump between positions but visually. Simply count from 0 to 5 and each time imagine your camera jumping at where the number is and taking a picture there. It's not very important, in the final implementation I'd only use `index_for` and jump to the index, but when testing the algorithm it's nice to have an immediate visualization of the positions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I have found as simpler formula for each rows:

[image: formula]

The code becomes trivial:

```rb
def index_for(n, cols)
  (n + cols * (n % 2)) / 2
end

(0..7).map{ |i| index_for(i, 8) }
=> [0, 4, 1, 5, 2, 6, 3, 7]
```

So, for now I'll just use this for each row. I'll wait a while in the case someone comes up with a better answer to my questions.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not convinced that maximizing the camera's distance traveled would make the car appear only once. It's probably more likely that the car would be seen in multiple, non-successive frames. That, too, would look pretty strange. But it's worth testing.

An easy way to test things is to represent your 2D array as a 1D array, do your scrambling, and then map it back to two dimensions. For example, this 2D array:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[ 6, 7, 8, 9,10]
[11,12,13,14,15]
```

becomes `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15]`

Now you can use your 1D algorithm to adjust the order, and then map it back to two dimensions.

I suspect that, rather than going exactly halfway, you'll want to choose a prime number that is not a divisor of the width or height.

Another possibility would be to just randomize the cells using a Fisher-Yates shuffle. That's easy to do, and in practice could very well do just as good a job of eliminating the car as would a deterministic scrambling algorithm.

Comment: Going 1D only works if you take in account the rows/cols, otherwise "distant" indices might be neighbors. I don't like the random solution because I want the captures to always happen in the same order when you re-capture the panorama, to minimize motor issues.

Comment: I added additonal information in the question about why the camera distance would likely solve my issue.